# View AIS- Data with QT?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, ais

anyone know how i can get the Data from a AIS site and view they in a QT Gui?
Can i save them in a SQL database ? 
I would have the data from this site : http://www.aishub.net/

AIS : The Automatic Identification System (AIS) is an automatic tracking system used on ships and by vessel traffic services (VTS) for identifying and locating vessels by electronically exchanging data with other nearby ships, AIS base stations, and satellites. When satellites are used to detect AIS signatures then the term Satellite-AIS (S-AIS) is used. AIS information supplements marine radar, which continues to be the primary method of collision avoidance for water transport.

Answer (score 0):

You should register account at http://www.aishub.net/ and subscribe to get access for their API described [here](http://www.aishub.net/xml-description-20.html). At desktop side you should build Qt application, that will not frequently then every minute call their API URL with your credentials using QNetworkRequest, retrieve QNetworkReply result output (this will be [XML](http://www.aishub.net/xml-samples.html) or JSON). And then parse the [XML](http://www.aishub.net/xml-samples.html) or JSON with Qt build-in classes for processing XML or JSON documents. After parsing you should display processed data in your preferred way, for example, sortable table view, or save in database, whatever.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer, i know that i must have a account, and i alredy have the json data. Firefox downloaded this, would c++ doing the same ? I think i must downloadet jsoncpp and libcurl.. but i dont know how i must write that at the moment :)

Comment: Qt 5 already contains classes to work efficiently with JSON. So, just check Qt documentation for that. For downloading the files check documentation for Qt Networking.

Comment: I use qt 4 with fedora, must i include the libs in properties at eclipse ?

Comment: If you use Qt 4 then to quickly handle JSON you can use QJson lib: http://qjson.sourceforge.net/ Because QJson lib has LGPL license, you must link your commercial code dynamically with this lib.

Answer (score 0):

This is not entirely a coding question.. you should found out how to get the data from the site on your own..
But anyway - there's a XML API on that site

Qt supports XML nicely.. you can store the xml if you want in file or in sqllite database, or just parse it an show it.

You can use some view widget to show the parsed data - something like QListView, QTableView ..