# QNetworkAccessManager open a json data with url

Tags: c++, json, eclipse, qt, network-programming

i would open a *.json data with a link in c++ / qt . When i open this url in Firefox, it returns a question for downloading this data. But at the moment my Code dosnt worked, every time is give an network error. I would read this json data in with my programm an put it in a QTableView.Must i use QNetworkAccessManager or is this the wrong way ?

```
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://google.de")));

    }
void Tester::serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    // At the end of that slot, we won't need it anymore
    reply->deleteLater();

    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
        QString Sdata = data;
        qDebug(data);
        qDebug("no Error");


    } else {
         cout<<"Error at Reply"<<endl;
         QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
         qDebug(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error message? try to obtain it with errorString() method call

Comment: it goes to the else , so it write : "Error at Reply"
Without this gDebug, it say's nothing.. thats the problem

Comment: I meant, that on error you should print out the error message by calling QNetworkReply::errorString() from your QNetworkReply instance. And then paste the error message text here.

Comment: "Host google.de not found "

Comment: Try to use http:// www. google. de instead of http://google.de

Comment: Of course, remove spaces from above

Answer (score 0):

Try to use url with www prefix:

```
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.de")));
```

Comment: thank you, but my original url is from ais , and dont have a www

Comment: I dont can post it, because there include my account name but this is the link : data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=exampleName&format=1&output=json&compress=0&latmin=50&latmax=58&lonmin=5&lonmax=10
This is the error when i use the URL : 
Protocol "" is unknown

Comment: @Erdbeerchen, is that your question too ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/25989358/2266412